# How to specify input audo decoder for FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

Some times when I transcode particular MP3 files to OPUS with FFMPEG I get many "overread" messages. I don't know what does this mean so far (and have also submitted [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1406558/what-does-overread-mean-when-transcoding-an-mp3-file-to-opus-with-ffmpeg) about this) yet suppose this is something bad and can harm the output. Swift research lead to a suggestion the problem is in the mp3float codec and can be solved by using mp3lib instead. How do I tell ffmpeg it should use mp3lib to decode the input?

Answer (score 2):

I have found out the answer to this question myself, let me share it:

Input decoder can be specified the same way like output encoder but should be specified before the input file name. Like this:

```
ffmpeg -c:a mp3 -i "file.mp3" -c:a libopus "file.opus"
```

This hasn't solved my problem, however, the "mp3" decoder still yields overread errors like "mp3float" does.